# Does "He thinks that one or two of the investigations would be good material for a novel or even for a suspense movie." sound natural?

Tags: meaning-in-context, subjunctives, reported-speech

Text:

> Roger wants to write a book about some of the interesting investigations from his company’s past. He thinks that one or two of the investigations would be good material for a novel or even for a suspense movie.

According to the text, #1 is correct, is #2 also correct?

1. What does Roger think that his company’s past investigations can provide? He thinks they can provide good material for a novel or even a suspense movie.
2. What does Roger think about a couple of investigations from his company’s past? He thinks they are good material for a novel or even a suspense movie.

Are they very wide-open questions?

Comment: Wide-open questions? As opposed to what?

Answer (score 1):

> He thinks that **one or two** *of the investigations* would be good
>   material for a novel or even for a suspense movie.

IMO, the reason for **#1** being correct is mentioned with a brief touch in the main example. The example explains "*one or two*", being in the scope of "some." It doesn't mention the exact number of scenarios, it's unclear. That's why it's more accurate than the #2.

In the case of **#2**, it directly mentions "*a couple of*" investigations for the matter, which is not completely true based on the actual example.

If I were to choose one answer for your question, I'd go for **#1**.